# Javascript breaks getting timezone without DST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set a user's timezone offset for PHP, being sent over ajax.  A page has been loaded with session data. If there is no data this gets put into the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var visitortime = new Date();
        visitortime.setMonth(1);
        var visitortimezone = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()*60;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/timezone/set/"+ visitortimezone,
            success: function(){
               location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

without the `visitortime.setMonth(1);` it runs fine and returns the right offset. But with it, it returns only 0.

I want to be able to get timezone offset without DST and then run DST check on the PHP side.

Comment: You cannot recover a timezone name having only its offset.

Comment: @zerkms I know that, I just want to get the offset seconds (without DST if in effect) since I do everything in unix timestamp its easy to then set to users timezone.

Comment: Oops, I thought you're doing `/ajax/timezone/get/` :-S Couldn't even realize someone will update something with `GET` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it with this bit of code:

```js
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var visitortime = new Date();
    var visitortimezone = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()*60;

    if(visitortime.dst()){
        visitortimezone = visitortimezone + 60*60;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/timezone/set/"+ visitortimezone,
        success: function(){
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Found here: [Check if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, and if it is for how many hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours).