# Convert date to UTC by ignoring Daylight Savings javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs, dst

I am in GMT +2 timezone and Daylight saving time on.

My requirement is to ask user a date and convert it into UTC without DST consideration.

when I do `console.log(new Date()),` 
it gives me `"Wed Oct 26 2016 18:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)"`

I want to send server a UTC format date which server is going to save in Database.

```
var extractTime = new Date(timeof.edtime); //timeof.edtime contains date given by user.
var d = extractTime.getDate();
var m = extractTime.getMonth();
var y = extractTime.getFullYear();
var h = extractTime.getHours();
var mm = extractTime.getMinutes();
timeof.edtime = moment(new Date(y, m, d, h, mm)).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

After converting to utc, `timeof.edtime` is `"2016-09-26 15:00"` because it subtract 3 hours to go to GMT. (subtracted 2 hours of standard turkish time) (subtracted -1 of DST)
I want to subtract date to UTC by not considering DST and in our case my expectation is to get hour as "16:00" and not "15:00"

How to convert date to UTC without Daylight saving consideration.
any solution using moment js or jquery will be helpful.
I am testing on chrome.

by browsing through few link it says `new Date()` will give in standard time and doesn't consider DST consideration but this is not I observed and created plunk to reproduce `new Date().toUTCString()` consider DST as well, how to avoid subtraction of DST? 
https://plnkr.co/edit/tjCOoJqXMHGzCD8B5LdL?p=preview

Comment: Do you need the time? If not, use 12:00:00

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't understood what u mean to say. I am interested in date and time both as converting to utc can change day before or after and time will definitely affect. so time and date both is important for me.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888430/5459839), you could make the time correction as follows:

```js
function compensateDST(dt) {
    var janOffset = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), 0, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
    var julOffset = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset();
    var dstMinutes = dt.getTimezoneOffset() - Math.max(janOffset, julOffset);
    dt = new Date(dt);
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() - dstMinutes);
    return dt;
}

// Use your date here:
var extractTime = new Date('2016-10-26 18:00');
// Truncate to minute precision:
var extractTime = new Date(extractTime.getTime() - extractTime.getTime() % 60000)
console.log('Local time:', extractTime.toString());
console.log('UTC time before correction:', extractTime.toISOString());
// Compensate for the DST shift:
var extractTime = compensateDST(extractTime);
console.log('UTC time  after correction:', extractTime.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> +180 is GMT+0300 (Turkey)

```
var x = new Date();
var newdate = new Date();
if((x.getTimezoneOffset()) != 180){
 newdate = new Date(x.getTime() + (60000*(x.getTimezoneOffset()+180)));
}
console.log(newdate);
```