# JavaScript - Best way to approach time zone (include daylight saving)

Tags: javascript, date

***javascript***

```
var get_tz = function(country_code){
 var tz = new Date(currentUtcTime.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: country_code}));
 return (tz.getHours()<10?"0"+tz.getHours():tz.getHours())+":"+(tz.getMinutes()<10?"0"+tz.getMinutes():tz.getMinutes());
}
```

`MDN` suggests the above method will be supported by most browser except mobile phone. I tried to run the page on my iPhone, and it worked as expected. Maybe I have the latest OS.

I have my doubts and wonder if there is a better way or new way to approach timezone problem.

***Read***

["Date.prototype.toLocaleString" from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Example:_Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments)

[How to check if the DST (Daylight Saving Time) is in effect and if it is what's the offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/how-to-check-if-the-dst-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-whats)

[Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

[iana](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2017b)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Date instances have access to system settings so can determine the current time zone offset using [*Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.gettimezoneoffset). The "*country_code*" argument is actually an IANA timezone code.

Comment: Yes `"country_code"` is IANA timezone code. I try to create a function that takes some input, then it returns date time for the given country. It must work on IE7 onward and mobile, but the `toLocaleString` works with only firefox, chrome and IE edge.

Comment: Then you will need to use a library, IE 7 certainly doesn't have support for time zones with *toLocaleString* (nor would I expect any browser from that era to support it as it wasn't part of ECMA-262 back then and ECMA-402 didn't exist, the first edition was December 2012).

Comment: Which lib would you recommend for this situation?

Comment: If you want to get the offset for particular time zones (identified by IANA timezone code) at particular dates and times, then [*Moment Timezone*](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) is a reasonable candidate.