# JavaScript Date.toString() returning the wrong time

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date that is saved in my database as UTC and looks `2019-04-25T08:47:14.813` when I console log it out.

I read to convert that to my local time I can just cast it as a `Date` and the do `toString()` and it would be my local time zone, but it doesn't seem to work with UK Daytime saving.

For example, if I take the string above and do this:

```
let d = new Date(item.lastChecked);
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(item.lastChecked);
```

The response I get is:

> Thu Apr 25 2019 08:47:14 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
>
> 2019-04-25T08:47:14.813

I don't want it to save (British Summer Time). I want it to say `9:47` instead.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the DST (Daylight Saving Time) is in effect and if it is what's the offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/how-to-check-if-the-dst-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-whats)

Comment: Is your machine's local time set correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `'Z'` (which indicates that date is in UTC) to your input string

```js
let d=new Date('2019-04-25T08:47:14.813'+'Z');

console.log(d.toString());
```