# How to handle DayLight saving while converting UT to EST in java script

Tags: javascript

Hi I wrote code around 6 months ago where I converted  UT datetime to EST.I used -5 offset.That time its worked fine but now as daylight saving time has changed now its not working properly.So if anyone having any ideas how to deal this please provide the solution.

Comment: read the doc https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the DST (Daylight Saving Time) is in effect and if it is what's the offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/how-to-check-if-the-dst-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-whats)