# JS - Given Timestamp Get UTC Offset For Time Zones Different From Local Zone

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I have **timestamps** therefore indicating the UTC +0 time.

I want to get the CT time related to those timestamps considering that the code can run from anywhere in the world.

now I can simply add the -6 Hours offset to those UTC timestamps, but that would not consider the DST possible offset.

And if I check the DST as in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888430/3755529) I would not consider that the code can be running in a place where the DST was observed while it was not observed in Chicago (CT) during the time the timestamp refers to (there is 3 weeks period, twice a year, where America has DST and Europe does NOT.. or the other way round).

So my question is: **at a given date, how can I know the UTC offset for a Time Zone which is not the Local Time Zone?**

EDIT:
I tried to use the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/3755529) using
 `new Date(1558361280000).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"})` 
it returns **5/20/2019, 9:08:00 AM** when instead it should have returned **5/20/2019, 3:08:00 PM**

Comment: I think you'll find https://momentjs.com/ is the solution to almost all date related problems.

Comment: @RockySims - Yes, but you'd need the moment-timezone extension also.  However, there are multiple other approaches, including built-in support via the `timeZone` option of `toLocaleString`, which are referenced in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @user3755529 - Don't think about it in terms of which offset to add or subtract.  Instead, identify [the IANA time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you need (such as `"America/Chicago"`) and apply it using an API that accepts those.

Comment: if I use `new Date(1558361280000).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"})` it returns **5/20/2019, 9:08:00 AM** when instead it should have returned **5/20/2019, 3:08:00 PM** ...this is because I am in London, I guess I have to correct first to the UTC by using `.getTimezoneOffset()` ?

Comment: I don't think it works because whenever you use `new Date()` you get dependent on the Local machine.