# how to get around the changeover to winter time in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dst

I use Moment.js in a planning application and I observe unexpected behaviors: the software calculates bad hours (+/-1hour spring/winter) when **i'm working before the day** of the time change (today for sunday) **but not when it is the day** (the same action on sunday is ok). It seems to anticipate the change when it's not what I want.

I tried to use the extension .utc () with no success.
Thanks for all suggestion.

```
// return hour from x position
function getHeure(x) {
    var dd = moment(heure0, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"); // heure0 contain day/hour of start
    var gt = moment(dd).add(parseInt(x / granul),'m') // 'x' is the x point in planning, 'granul' the ratio of min/px
if (dd.date()==27 && dd.month()==9) gt.add(1,'hours')   // current workaround for France in 2019...
    return gt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the same approach as this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888430/3292394

I have used the solution above and it works perfectly.

Regards,
user3292394