# How do I convert certain Date object to the corresponding time in germany?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Let's say I have a Date object like this:

```
let dateToConvert = new Date(date_string) // represents certain time like 12th Aug 11PM in India
```

What I want to achieve is to design a function like this:

```
getGermanDate(dateToConvert): Date {
   // What should be written here?
}
```

The function should return Date object that is the time in Germany at the time that is in dateToConvert object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use native JavaScript functions to convert ([toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)), or you could use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) (which is more flexible).

For the toLocaleString call I'm also specifying a Germany date format (by passing "de-DE" to the locale parameter, you could use whichever locale you wish.

```js
function getGermanDate(input) {
    return moment.tz(input, "Europe/Berlin");
}

/* Using moment timezone */
let timestamp = "2020-08-12 23:00:00";
let timeIndia = moment.tz(timestamp, "Asia/Kolkata");
let timeGermany = getGermanDate(timeIndia);
console.log("Time (India):", timeIndia.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
console.log("Time (Germany):", timeGermany .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));

/* Using native JavaScript */
let dateToConvert = new Date("2020-08-12T23:00:00+0530");

console.log("Time (India, native):", dateToConvert.toLocaleString('en-IN', { timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata' }));
console.log("Time (Germany, native):", dateToConvert.toLocaleString('de-DE', { timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Formatting of javascript dates is covered in numerous other questions. A particular timezone can be specified using the *timeZone* option with [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or for more control use the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and *format* option (timezones are specified using an [IANA representative location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to apply historic and DST changes), e.g.

```js
let d = new Date();

// toLocaleString, default format for language de
console.log(d.toLocaleString('de',{timeZone:'Europe/Berlin', timeZoneName: 'long'}));

// DateTimeFormat.format with specific options
let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  minute: '2-digit',
  timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin',
  timeZoneName: 'short'
});
console.log(f.format(d));
```

You might also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61566171/257182).