# How can I use native JavaScript to get the timestamp of a specific point in time in a specific IANA time zone?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I cannot solve the seemingly simple problem of getting on my *Node.js* server (UTC) the timestamp of a certain point in time in a certain IANA timezone. Something like this:

```
getTsByTimezone('America/New_York', 2021, 2, 2, 17, 0, 0, 0) => int
```

I would not like to use third-party libraries *Moment* or the like.

Thank you!

Comment: [*This answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364310/257182) to [*Calculate Timezone offset only for one particular timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361914/calculate-timezone-offset-only-for-one-particular-timezone) might be what you're after. Given 2021-03-02T17:00:00, America/New_York it returns "2021-03-02 22:00:00" and offset -05:00.

Comment: @RobG thanks for your comment. I am currently using a similar approach. It doesn't look pretty. We need to create 5-6 `Date` objects for one moment in time, and my computer starts to slow down when processing an array of 200 such moments. I was hoping there was a way to make it easier.

Comment: You should only need to create 2 Dates: one for the initial offset estimate and one to check it's correct. More are needed only if the offset shifts the date over a daylight saving boundary, which should be rare, and only two additional dates are required at a maximum. The code at the linked answer runs in 3 to 5 ms locally, and that includes all the DOM stuff and additional processing of Dates for comparison.

Comment: @RobG in any case, this can be redone in response to the question I asked. If you do this I can mark it as correct.