# How to covert date time to local date time using timezone string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to convert given Date time to local Date time, when input Date time and timeZone is given separately as below

1. Date -20220120080000 ('yyyymmddHHMMSS')
2. timezone string -("Australia/Perth")

How to convert above timezone to local Date time without using moment library ?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: In my case timezone string -("Australia/Perth") is for input date and that I want to convert  into local

Comment: I don't think the marked duplicate is correct. The OP wants to create a Date for a particular timestamp in a certain location. The duplicate starts with a Date and generates a timestamp for a place with a different offset. A more likely duplicate is [*Calculate Timezone offset only for one particular timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361914/calculate-timezone-offset-only-for-one-particular-timezone).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use moment, this becomes pretty straightforward.
Check [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-shape-lmenxo).

```js
let date = "20220120080000";
const format = "YYYYMMDDHHmmss";
let tz = "Australia/Perth";

const remoteTime = moment.tz(date, format, tz);
const localTime = moment(remoteTime).local();
```

Comment: Can we do this using javascript, without using moment library.

Comment: @AnkitDable—yes.

Comment: @robG, Could you please assist me how we can do this using JavaScript?

Comment: @AnkitDable—see [*Calculate Timezone offset only for one particular timezone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361914/calculate-timezone-offset-only-for-one-particular-timezone)