# Javascript/jQuery to display hour in loop from today until tomorrow date

Tags: javascript

I need to display hour from specific hour until specific hour.

Assume I need the hour from `03-Jul-2021 07:00` until `04-Jul-2021 07:00`.

```js
var date = new Date;
var hour = date.getHours();

var getHour = []
for( var i=7; i<hour; i++ ) {
  getHour.push(i+":00");
}

console.log(getHour);
```

How can I do that?

So the result should be:

```
07:00
08:00
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
04:00
05:00
06:00
07:00
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

1. It does not hardcode the time in the loop
2. It pads the hours

Missing: handling DST switching. We can use the .getTimezoneOffset() if we want to have a list that has the correct times across DST

```js
const anHour = 60*60*1000;
const getTimes = (start, end) => {
  const hours = [];
  for (let i = start, n = end.getTime(); i.getTime() <= n; i.setTime(i.getTime()+anHour)) hours.push(`${String(i.getHours()).padStart(2,"0")}:00`);
  return hours;
};


let startDate = new Date(2021, 6, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0);
let endDate = new Date(2021, 6, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(getTimes(startDate, endDate));

// If you do not need to specify dates and times, then have a static array of 
const times = ["07:00",  "08:00",  "09:00",  "10:00",  "11:00",  "12:00",  "13:00", "14:00",  "15:00", "16:00",  "17:00",  "18:00",  "19:00",  "20:00", "21:00",  "22:00",  "23:00",  "00:00",  "01:00",  "02:00",  "03:00",  "04:00",  "05:00",  "06:00",  "07:00" ];
```

Handling DST would need something like
[How to check if DST (Daylight Saving Time) is in effect, and if so, the offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66866868/295783)

Comment: Hi, how about if startDate and endDate dynamically?

Comment: I do not understand. My function will take any start and end - what do you mean by dynamic

Comment: Hi, I mean startDate will auto get from the current date and endDate will auto get from current date + 1.

Comment: That is not what you asked: `Assume I need the hour from 03-Jul-2021 07:00 until 04-Jul-2021 07:00.`

Comment: It's just assume. The actual is I need the date is not manually

Comment: If you need any date from 07 to 07 next day then no need to generate!!!

Comment: The date is auto, but the time is from 07.00 to 07.00

Comment: But the array is the same ALWAYS UNLESS you want to skip 03:00 in October

Comment: A list of hours from 07:00 to 07:00 will always be the same for any date unless we need to handle DST. I do not understand your use case here

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it should be something like

```js
var date = new Date;
var hour = date.getHours();

var getHour = []
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  getHour.push((hour + i) % 24 + ":00");
}

console.log(getHour); // 8:00, 9:00, ... 8:00
```